# string split in java is not working as expected giving wrong result

Tags: java, string, split

```
String text="2|919505485043|2013-08-08 12:57:50|2013-08-08 12:58:04|2013-08-08 12:58:08|ANSWER";
```

I want to split string using `|`.I have the above string in java.When i used

```
System.out.println(text.split("|").length);
```

I am getting the result 82.What might be the wrong here.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) uses a regular expression as it argument. The pipe character `|` has special meaning (meaning OR) prevents the String from being split internally at every literal `|`.

It should be escaped

```
text.split("\\|").length
```

otherwise the complete `String` will be used when determining the length

Comment: +1 That's a really interesting way to solve that. I didn't know that until I read this post. Great job.

Comment: great help indeed. was scratching my head.

Answer (score 8):

[`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses regular expressions, and `|` has a special meaning within regular expressions.

Options:

- Escape the `|` manually: `text.split("\\|")`
- Escape the `|` programmatically: `text.split(Pattern.quote("|"))`
- Use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class instead, to avoid using regular expressions at all

Personally I would go for the latter approach - I think it's actually a design flaw that `String.split` uses regular expressions at all, and it's unclear in calling code.

If you *really* want to use `String.split`, I'd definitely use `Pattern.quote` to make it clear to anyone reading the code *why* you're escaping it - just using `"\\|"` isn't very self-documenting, IMO.

Comment: I like to see the addition of a String.split(char seperator) method to cater for exactly this fairly-common scenario. God knows the implementation would be simple enough. I remember seeing this done in one very long, very ugly, line of ANSI-C code. The good-ole-days when men where men, and bugs cost extra.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the escape character,

```
text.split("\\\|");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put `\\` you forgot this.

```
text.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Sstring {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text="2|919505485043|2013-08-08 12:57:50|2013-08-08 12:58:04 |2013-08-08 12:58:08|ANSWER";
        System.out.println(text.split("\\|").length);
        String str[] = text.split("\\|");

        for(String i:str){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guava, as usual!

```
Splitter.on("|").split("your_text")
```

This returns an Iterable.